# Visual Studio Web Site Published - Access Denied

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, publish

I am trying to publish a web site to a network location, and I'm getting access denied.  I know its not an issue with the feature, as I published to a different network location OK.  So what permissions are needed for this feature to work?

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on the feature. Can you compare security settings between both network locations and identify what's different between the two?

Comment: are you running the VS2010 in admin?

Comment: An admin on my machine, not the network.  Yes there would be much different security settings, and I definitely expect this is the case.  But I need to know what permission I need to request to do this :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to run your web site as it is WITHOUT precompilation, by browsing to http://localhost/website/ , you will see an error message to what you are seeing when you try to publish. This is because the identity needs both read and write access to the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder.

A possible workaround is for you to grant read/write permissions to the current used account to the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder.

By default, when you compile a Web application the compiled code is placed in the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder. This folder is a subdirectory of the location where you installed the .NET framework. Typically, the location is the following:
Copy

```
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versionNumber\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

The .NET installation process creates the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder and assigns access permissions to the ASP.NET local user account, which has the high-trust permissions needed to access your compiled code.

Comment: OK, but what is the account, as I personally have access to this folder?

Comment: Compilation of your web site is executed by ASP.NET using some working process like aspnet_wp.exe or w3wp.exe.  If your application don't use impersonation then your working process have used default account for particular working process. So, for IIS 5 you should give permisiion for ASPNET account and for IIS 6 - NETWORK SERVICE account.

Comment: IIS 7 is the app pool account, to add to this.